# How to disable (make invisible) the robot in firefox with RSelenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, firefox, rselenium

I would like to omit the visibility of my scraping on a given website using firefox browser. I tried to use the option `"marionette.enabled" = FALSE` without success. Notice the little robot in the upper left corner of the browser. Among other things, according to my research, this makes it clear to the site that there is a robot browsing. Follow a example.

```r
library(RSelenium)

port <- 4445L

extra = list(`moz:firefoxOptions` = list(args = list("--disable-extensions","--disable-popup-blocking","--ignore-certificate-errors","--disable-notifications","--disable-geolocation"),
                                         prefs = list("geo.enabled"=FALSE,                                                  
                                                      "marionette.enabled"=FALSE)))
myip = "localhost"

rD <- rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"),
               remoteServerAddr = myip,
               extraCapabilities=extra,
               verbose=TRUE,
               check = FALSE,
               port = port)

driver <- rD[["client"]]

driver$navigate("https://www.google.com.br/maps")
```

Comment: A little more context on *why* you want to make it look like your robot browsing isn't robot browsing might help us feel like we're not helping you do something unethical.

Comment: You are right. I'm scraping data from a real estate agency. On this site, I scrape information such as property price, area, etc. I could do this manually. Therefore, I understand that this is public and legal. However, my algorithm makes this task faster, more efficient and less tedious. I feel that this site has robot detectors, and making it very difficult to scrape data, such as locking phone tags among other devices. Therefore, I believe that omitting the information that there is a robot acting would allow such work.